# Spreadsheet source of a programmed trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the publish/subscribe pattern to help me build more complex apps in the GAS environment.

Since it is now possible to install a trigger programmatically, I would have expected being able to retrieve within a listener the spreadsheet id where a particular trigger was installed, when the event is fired:

```
function setTrigger(){
  var triggerBuilder = ScriptApp.newTrigger("listen"),
      onEditTrigger = triggerBuilder.forSpreadsheet('some-id').onEdit().create();
}

function listen(e){
  var ssId = e['range'].getSheet().getParent().getId(); //ssId = 'some-id'

}
```

ssId will actually be the id of the spreadsheet where setTrigger() is: not very useful.

Maybe I'm running low on imagination this late in the night, but I see no way of implementing this very useful pattern (100 created spreadsheets, one listener, a set of actions common to all these spreadsheets, but no way to interact with the particular caller since it cannot be identified).

Any help or comment would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Well, maybe that question was a true "stack overflow", a bit outside the limits of expectation.

I succeeded retrieving the calling spreadsheet likewise:

A) Create a lookup sheet where I keep track of callback functions for particular events;

B) In the script where the event was created, code a function that installs every function indexed in the previous sheet in "this".

Now, whenever an event is triggered, the script where the trigger was installed is called, with any and all parameter/property I put in the listener.

It solves a major deficiency in GAS: if I install a trigger programmatically on a particular sheet, how do I retrieve that calling sheet?  Further more, I now can programmatically remove that trigger, associated with a particular sheet, when that sheet is removed or when I decide to stop receiving events from that sheet.

Thanks to both posters for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.Not tested, because I'm new to script handlers, and I couldn't get your script to log ssID.
Each event has a source property, which is just the trigger's spreadsheet source.
I pulled this code from the docs:

> Trigger Source: A trigger is executed when an event occurs that the trigger is listening to. Each trigger is associated with an EventType that can be fetched using Trigger.getEventType(). For example, an EventType could be CLOCK, meaning it is a time-based trigger, or ON_OPEN, meaning it is a trigger that is executed when a Spreadsheet is opened. However, each event has a source as well. For example, an OnEdit event in a Spreadsheet must have a source. This source can be fetched using Trigger.getTriggerSource(), and its value is represented by an enum in ScriptApp.TriggerSource.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  r.setComment("Last modified: " + (new Date()));
}
```

Comment: That'd be swell, but, in the context described in my question, there is no **e.source** property, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1300) for the problem where the range parameter returns the incorrect parent sheet. You can star that issue to get updates.

Comment: Ok...  You write "This appears to be working as intended" in that open issue, but i gather it's not the case...  I had already read that issue...  Not clear at all...  I'll star the issue, if that helps.  Could not reproduce the problem described.

Comment: If you scroll to the bottom you'll see I later reopened it. I misunderstood the original question.

Comment: Thanks. Did find a workaround for the issue you mentioned.  Seems like SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getSheet().getSheetId() and SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation() provide accurate information (meaning the sheet ID where the range actually is and the range where the data was entered).  If you know the originating spreadsheet "publishing" the edit event, by way of the technique I described above in my answer, you would be able to retrieve the value.  I'll need to isolate the code to do that, since fixing the issue will probably break the workaround in a very bad way.