# How to determine source script of installable trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

I have a trigger that I can't find! At least, I can't find it easily, and may have to resort to the brute force method.

I've got more than a hundred scripts and spreadsheets-with-scripts, and somewhere in there I have a function called `colorRows` that is set up as a trigger. I know that, because it shows up in my triggers list:

[image: All your triggers]

How can I find the script that contains `colorRows`?

- I've tried using Search in Google Drive, but it appears to be unable to find the content of scripts contained in spreadsheets. (It does index standalone scripts, so that did narrow down my search to just spreadsheets.)
- I can open every spreadsheet, then open the script, and search - brute force. No thank you, that's still some 75 sheets.
- Script Services `getProjectTriggers()` is project-based, as the name implies, and only works within the project it's running in.
- The title of [Spreadsheet source of a programmed trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045286/spreadsheet-source-of-a-programmed-trigger) sounded good, but is quite different.
- I don't want to stop the trigger (that's easy), I want to find the code. So [How to Stop Orphaned Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201847/how-to-stop-orphaned-triggers) is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a record of this complaint, [Issue 146](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=146). It was raised in July 2010, and closed as *Won't Fix* in Feb 2011.